# If I expose a bowl of curd to sunlight,then will the bacteria undergo mutation?

Tags: microbiology

Since bacteria undergo mutation while exposed to the sunlight, if a bowl of curd is exposed to sunlight, will the bacteria undergo mutation?

Answer (score 0):

Mutations happen all the time. It does not take sunlight for mutations to happen, whether in bacteria or in eukaryotes. It mainly just take DNA replication for mutations to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneous mutations occur in all cells (more frequently in bacterial cells) whenever DNA replicates.

No matter the location of the curd, bacterias from that enviroment will have muattions because they replicate.
 UV rays from the sunlight will also cause some mutations and extensive DNA damage in some bacterias that will eventually die, while others will get mutations that aren't as harmful for the cell.

Human cells, compared to bacterias have proof-reading and safety-check mechanisms that prevent mutated cells (UV damage, normal replication, viruses, etc) from spreading around-cancer.